# ERROR 1000 using DESCRIBE keyword in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to run my Pig code on Eclipse, but the following error occurred :

`ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "line_target_group "" at line 27, column 1.
Was expecting one of:`

This is a part of my code :

```
23 line_target_group = GROUP line_target BY line_cd;
24
25 DESCRIBE line_target_group;
26
27 line_target_group : {
28   group : int,
29   line_target : {
30     line_cd : int,
31     station_cd1 : int,
32     station_cd2 : int,
33     s_km : double,
34     s_point : bytearray
35   }
36 }
```